# adding custom TextView at some position?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom TextView and I want to add those TextViews dynamically at some particular position, like below an EditText. Can somebody tell me how to do this? I want to add my custom textView dynamically through java and not by XML , how to use addView() for this?
[image]

Part of XML is (as my XML file is very large in size):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainStaffScrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <!-- buttons,spinners,edittexts etc-->

 <Button
   android:id="@+id/specialisationStaffSpinner"
   style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
   android:text="@string/names" />

 <!-- here i want to add my custom view-->

 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: This can be done, but you'll want to post more details of the existing layout.  Is it a LinearLayout?  A RelativeLayout?  If it comes from XML, can you post the xml?

Comment: put a empty layout view at the place where you want to add the custom textview ..... get this layout into your activity by its id .. and add the custom textview into the empty layout which you define in the xml.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an empty LinearLayout at the place where you want to insert your custom TextView, then reference it in your java code and then use addView() on the LinearLayout. Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 3):

- put a empty layout view at the place where you want to add the custom
  textview
- get this layout into your activity by its id
- and add the custom textview into the empty layout which you define in the
  xml

Answer (score 0):

use the Relative layout as the parent it gives you power to achieve what you want 
create the layout params and use the addRule function

like this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ButtonId);

        adsLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in 3-steps if you're using RelativeLayout.

1. Ensure both top and bottom buttons have valid Id's.
2. Initialize and specify the location using RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, topButton.getId());
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, bottomButton.getId());`

3.Add view.

```
targetContainer.addView(customTextView, params);
```

It will be harder without RelativeLayout though.

Comment: I am not using relative layout, i have my xml complete with linear layout

Comment: If you know before hand where you need to add the custom textviews, use R4chi7's answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout)
TextView txt1 = new TextView(this, R.drawable.customexml);
linearLayout.addView(txt1);
```

Comment: this will not add the view as shown by the image...i have tried this earlier

Answer (score 0):

Just make the edit text gone to begin with, find the reference in code and update it and set its visibility to View.VISIBLE

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainStaffScrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <!-- buttons,spinners,edittexts etc-->

 <Button
   android:id="@+id/specialisationStaffSpinner"
   style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
   android:text="@string/names" />

  <View
   android:visiblity="gone"
  android:id="+id/customView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   </View>


 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```